# Minecraft for iPads

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have 4 kids each with their own iPad. Can we share the one download of Minecraft: Pocket Edition (all play at the same time on different iPads under the same account)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes they can, i have my own ipad, and my two younger sister have their own, on IOS minecraft is just another app, so like all other apps, it cab be shared with multiple users with the same account. Multiplayer can be played together through Lan (Local Area Network) and name change can be found in minecrafts Settings. So one copy of the game can be shared and used by the one account.

This is an excerpt to the P.C version of Multiplayer, but Lan will work with an offline version.

Comment: IOS version does not phone home, currently there is a separate app for ONLINE multiplayer, which will cost more when Beta is finished to play, but Lan has been available right from the start, and it can be played with the same purchased game; on another device.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201085) to share purchases.

EDIT:

After some comment warfare I've come to the conclusion that it does. Besides, what does it hurt to try between two devices?

Comment: I don't believe this would help them at all... The Minecraft servers would still have to authenticate four different people all logging in to the same account at once, which isn't going to happen.

Comment: Wait, does Minecraft phone home? It shouldn't matter on single player or LAN.

Comment: Unless you are playing in offline mode, the game authenticates with the Minecraft servers, in order to prevent unauthorized use of the game, as in this instance.

Comment: This: seems to say it's supported. http://cdn1.appleinsider.com/gallery/10125-2188-140808-Family_Sharing-l.png

Comment: True, but to me that doesn't necessarily mean that multiple people can use it at once... just means that the app itself can be shared across devices. I still imagine there would be a problem if two people tried to sign in at once.
Edit: apparently it does work, according to the other answer. Oh well.

Comment: @Johonn Does it authenticate with Mojang on Pocket Edition? The game doesn't require a logon like the PC edition, but I guess it could use the ID the game was purchased with as authentication, which might prevent multiple instances running under the same ID. (Disclaimer, I use Android, not IOS)

Comment: I don't actually own pocket edition, I was just assuming that the same structure would be in place. I guess I don't understand the mobile system well enough.

Comment: @Johonn you could be right, I don't know myself, as whilst I own Pocket Edition on both Android and IOS, I'm strictly a PC player of Minecraft.

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure it'll work. Besides, what will it hurt to try it between two?

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple devices using the same AppleID/app purchase, and they can use the app at the same time.
I use an old iPod Touch as a "server". This allows my kids to play in the same world all the time without the world only existing on one kids iPad. If that kid isn't playing, no one else can play in that world.

For a home LAN MinecraftPE server, I simply:
- Used an old iPod Touch (Gen3 or newer), 
- Installed the app (free since I already bought it), 
- Set lock screen time to "never" (Settings > General > Auto-Lock > Never),
- Start the app
- Set volume to zero
- Place on shelf on charger
- Forget

This gives me a free, full feature, no maintenance Minecraft server.
  You can copy an existing world from your current device with free programs like iExplorer.